# Setup and Initialize Route in Glimmer js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, glimmer.js

Not long ago I hear about [glimmer](https://glimmerjs.com/) and decide to try it out.

Now I already try to do their tutorial and see the todo-mvc that glimmer already create but it seems that they use [navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) to navigate through page.

I want to know if there's any proper way to setup route since previously I use ember.js and to setup route I just need to add another route at router.js.

Because of using navigo now I use code like this to navigate through routes

component.ts

```js
import Component, { tracked } from '@glimmer/component';
import Navigo from 'navigo';

const router = new Navigo(null, true);

export default class MainPage extends Component {
    @tracked routeName;

    constructor(options){
        super(options);

        router
        .on({
            '/': () => { this.routeName = 'home'; },
            '/posts': () => { this.routeName = 'postList'; }
        })
        .resolve();
    }
};
```

template.hbs

```html
<div>
    <a href="#/posts"><button>See All Posts</button></a>

    {{#if (eq routeName 'postList')}}
        <post-list />
    {{/if}}
    {{#if (eq routeName '404')}}
        <h1>PAGE NOT FOUND</h1>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Above code is working but it need me to have # after the domain. I think need to find another way or maybe more proper way than this one.

Comment: Glimmer has no router. If you need a router I would recommend to use ember. Basically ember is glimmer + router + other goodies. The end goal is that you cam just install the parts you need, and then use glimmer+ember router without other ember features, but thats not possible yet.

Comment: I don't know that the ember-cli has a way to just toss in add-ons since it wires them into Ember, not Glimmer as a stand alone, but I like the question @Dio . I think it's a natural question to ask and hopefully 6 months from now a there is a way to answer it  using the existing pipeline from tildeio to glue Glimmer together with https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current answer to your question is that Glimmer does not have such concept as routes. In future, you should be able to install parts of Ember - such as Ember routing to your Glimmer app.

Basically, it will work like this:

Glimmer application -> Installing all Ember packages = Ember application.

Or:

Glimmer application -> Installing only a few Ember packages = Glimmer + parts from Ember such as routing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is explained further in the opening keynote at Emberconf this year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEuY4GqwrUE